# how to count_documents over a partial object match in an array?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

This is what i have in my mongodb

[image]

```
{
    events: [
        {
           event_time: "31",
           team: "home",
           event: "goal"
        },
        {
           event_time: "72",
           team: "home",
           event: "goal"
        },
   ]
}
```

the "events" array is made up of objects that has a key value pair "event_time" and other keys

Here is how i am trying to query them
[image]

```
        filter = {
        "$expr": { 
            "$and": [
                {"$eq": ["$seasonToScrap2", season]},
                { "$in": [ { "event_time": "27" }, "$events", ] },
            ] 
        }
    }

    htGoal = db[table].count_documents(filter)
```

The problem is i can only get a match if the entire object with every key and value is a match.

I only wish to query using event_time key value pair. like this
{
"event_time": "27"
}

How should i do it?

Comment: Please post content in text instead of screenshots.

Comment: whats wrong with filter

Comment: What happens with `filter = {"seasonToScrap2": season, "events.event_time": "27"}`?  ... similar to this [mongoplayground.net example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/-LF0x-8qiTc).